# Azure Key Vault integration with spring boot project with two user identities attached to the VM

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

We are followed the below documentation for integrating azure key vault in our spring boot project

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1407131/spring-boot-application-azure-key-vault-client-cer

When we deployed our spring boot app on Azure VM ( which has two user assigned identities attached to it) it is failing and it works when we have just one user identities on the VM.

The two user assigned identities attached to VM one belongs to us and other one belongs to operational teams, so we just mentioned 1 user identity in our spring boot property files but not the other one

Our property file looks exactly the same below

#AZURE KEY VAULT CONFIG
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=KEYVAULT_ENDPOINT
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=TENANT_ID

what needs to be done to make it work with just one user identity on our property file but two user identities attached to VM

Do I need to make any updates to my property files to make it working ? if so what ?